# conditional function to change post-meta background image

Tags: post-meta

I have this CSS setup for my blog posts meta information. But there are certain categories where I would like to use another image in the same spot and not display the meta information. I'm not quite sure how to do it.

```
.entry-meta {
background: url("images/dish_blogtitle.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
color: #666666;
float: left;
font-size: 13px;
font-style: italic;
height: 100px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-left: -125px;
margin-top: 5px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: -80px;
width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: does you theme use `post_class()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class within the post div? if so, you could use the category dependant css classes as a basis for individual styles.

Comment: yes, I use them. I just didn't realize they were that powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Have you checked the classes on your `<body>` element?**

It depends on the theme but WordPress has a function
[body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)
that dynamically adds a bunch of useful classes in there. It may look like this:

```
<body class="archive category category-news category-2 two-column content-sidebar">
```

As you can see it is a powerful helper as you can easily accomplish complex style changes by prepending your definitions with these classes. In your case it could be:

```
.category-something .entry-meta {
   /* whatever style changes you need */
}
```

If there is no such awesomeness in your `<body>` element then you can add it there yourself very easily:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

The [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18864/conditional-function-to-change-post-meta-background-image/18869#18869) provided by @xLRDxREVENGEx is certainly valid and points in the right direction. It's certainly worth (re)thinking what approach is the right one for your use case.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it write but you should think about looking into WordPress template hierarchy structure. Check out this page from the wordpress codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

In your template folder create a file with category-slug.php or category-id.php

replace the slug word with the slug you assigned the category or put the id that is assigned to the category

Comment: another good solution. but the css route with custom body classes is less work for what I am trying to accomplish. thanks for the answer!